# Group BY Day in the Android?

Tags: android, json

Can We Parse the JSON Data As Group BY Day in the Android.I am not able to generate logic how to parse the JSON Data as in Day.

**JSON Data**

```
[
 {
    "ID": 2012,
    "ClassRoom_ID": 1,
    "DayOfTheWeek": "6",
    "StartTime": "2017-03-20T12:37:00",
    "EndTime": "2017-03-20T10:37:00",
    "EmpID": 8,
    "classNO": 8,
    "CourseID": 1012,
    "teachers": {
      "EmpID": 8,
      "NAME": "Hunter Fuentes",
      "PHONE_NO": "04 37 33 81 11",
      "MOBILE_NO": "16890727-0931",
      "EMAIL": "id.ante.dictum@egetnisi.ca",
      "DESIGNATION": "Abdul Norris",
      "PERMANENT_ADDRESS": "492-3934 Nunc Road",
      "TEMP_ADDRESS": "P.O. Box 108, 1841 Sodales Rd.",
      "DOB": "1867-09-19T00:00:00",
      "TEACHER_OR_NONTEACHER": "T",
      "NATIONAL_ID_NO": "5",
      "MARITAL_STATUS": "M",
      "GENDER": "M",
      "QUALIFICATION": "SLC",
      "DEPTID": 5,
      "JoiningDate": "2017-10-17T00:00:00",
      "departments": null,
      "Photo": null,
      "base64": null
    },
    "courses": {
      "CourseID": 1012,
      "CourseName": "Math",
      "CourseLevel": 0,
      "CourseInstructor1": "Kennedy Joseph",
      "CourseInstructor2": "Haviva Nielsen",
      "CourseInstructor3": "Bruno Fry",
      "ClassNo": 8,
      "UT_PM": 20,
      "UT_FM": 50,
      "Terminal_PM": 40,
      "Terminal_FM": 100
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": 2013,
    "ClassRoom_ID": 5,
    "DayOfTheWeek": "2",
    "StartTime": "2017-03-20T10:37:00",
    "EndTime": "2017-03-20T11:37:00",
    "EmpID": 5,
    "classNO": 8,
    "CourseID": 2013,
    "teachers": {
      "EmpID": 5,
      "NAME": "Kennedy Joseph",
      "PHONE_NO": "05 49 81 27 99",
      "MOBILE_NO": "16330902-1552",
      "EMAIL": "Cras@metusfacilisislorem.co.uk",
      "DESIGNATION": "Mason Nielsen",
      "PERMANENT_ADDRESS": "Ap #468-4208 Etiam Rd.",
      "TEMP_ADDRESS": "Ap #383-2738 Dui Road",
      "DOB": "1956-01-21T00:00:00",
      "TEACHER_OR_NONTEACHER": "T",
      "NATIONAL_ID_NO": "8",
      "MARITAL_STATUS": "S",
      "GENDER": "M",
      "QUALIFICATION": "Others",
      "DEPTID": 5,
      "JoiningDate": "2016-10-03T00:00:00",
      "departments": null,
      "Photo": "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",
      "base64": null
    },
    "courses": {
      "CourseID": 2013,
      "CourseName": "English",
      "CourseLevel": 0,
      "CourseInstructor1": "Gabriel Boone",
      "CourseInstructor2": "Georgia Reeves",
      "CourseInstructor3": "Doris Marquez",
      "ClassNo": 8,
      "UT_PM": 15,
      "UT_FM": 100,
      "Terminal_PM": 40,
      "Terminal_FM": 100
    }
  }
]
```

**FragmentClassTest**

```
public class FragmentClassTest extends Fragment {


    LinearLayout sunday, sundaySchedule, monday, mondayClass, tuesday, tuesdayClass, wednesday, wednesdayClass, thrusday, thrusdayClass, friday, fridayClass;

    public static final String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/employeeApi/timeTableByClass";
    String master_id;
    TextView WeekofDay, mondaysubject;
    String day;


    ListView listViewStudentClass;
    List<ClassScheduleStudent> classschedulestudent = new ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent>();
    String access_token;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_schedule_listitem_student, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        sunday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sunday);
        monday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.monday);
        tuesday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tuesday);
        wednesday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.wednesday);
        thrusday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.thrusday);
        friday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.friday);


        sundaySchedule = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sunday_class);
        mondayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.monday_class);
        tuesdayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tuesday_class);
        wednesdayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.wednesday_class);
        thrusdayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.thrusday_class);
        fridayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.friday_class);


        WeekofDay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DayofWeek);

        listViewStudentClass = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_class_schedule);


        //   sundaySchedule.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //   mondayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   tuesdayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   wednesdayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   thrusdayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   fridayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(getContext());
        session.checkLogin();
        master_id = session.getMasterId();
        access_token = session.getAccesstToken();


        makeJsonObjectRequest();
        return view;
    }

    ClassScheduleStudent classScheduleStudent;


    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL = Navigation_URL + "?Sid=" + master_id;
        System.out.println(URL);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_student_fee = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<JSONObject> dayone=new ArrayList<>();
                            List<JSONObject> daytwo=new ArrayList<>();
                            List<JSONObject> daythree=new ArrayList<>();




                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                day = jsonObject.getString("DayOfTheWeek");


                                switch (day) {
                                    case "1":  //for sunday

                                        String classId=jsonObject.getString( "ClassRoom_ID");
                                        dayone.add(jsonObject);

                                        //...... parse data//
                                        break;
                                    case "2":  //for monday

                                        break;
                                    case "3":
//...... do your code//
                                        break;
                                    case "4":
//...... do your code//
                                        break;
                                    case "5":
                                        break;
                                    case "6":
                                        break;
                                    case "7":
                                        break;
                                }






                             /*   String Description = jsonObject.getString("teachers");
                                JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(Description);

                                //   JSONArray descriptionArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Description");

                                for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObjectinner = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);


                                  String  Descriptionlist = jsonObjectinner.getString("NAME");


                                }   */


                                student_list_student_fee.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(day));


                            }


                            //  JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("studentDetails");
                            // studentInformation.GuardianStudentId = studentDetails_obj.getString("StdID");


                            //  JSONObject studentDetails_obj1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("stdCategory");
                            //  studentInformation.Category = studentDetails_obj1.getString("Category");
                            //  studentInformation.CategoryId = studentDetails_obj1.getString("Cat_ID");


                            for(JSONObject jobj: dayone){
                                String classId=jobj.getString("ClassRoom_ID"); //class id of dayone
                            }

                            ClassScheduleStudentAdapter customFeeListStudentAdapter = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_student_fee);
                            listViewStudentClass.setAdapter(customFeeListStudentAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }
/*
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("id", master_id);
                map.put("accessID", accessID);
                map.put("currentUser", master_id);
                return map;

            }    */
        };


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

> Can this be groupedbyDay?i am totally confused.How can this be done.

Comment: Try to store all data in database and get data based on week day.

Comment: how can the day be seperated with if else condition? or through which

Comment: If you add all data in database then you get respective day data with query as per your requirement.

Comment: is there any way without storing in the sqlite database.Can't we check the day int and set in the required textView?

Comment: More efficient way is i have suggested otherwise you have to check data for each day or store each day data on collection.

Comment: I will try storing in the Database .@HareshChhelana

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138592/discussion-between-ghimire-and-haresh-chhelana).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved using idea of kiranBenny slution**

```
 private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL = Navigation_URL + "?Sid=" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule_sunday = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule_monday = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule_tuesday = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule_wednesday = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule_thursday = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule_friday = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule_saturday = new ArrayList<>();
                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {


                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                day = jsonObject.getString("DayOfTheWeek");

                                if (day.equals("1")) {
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teachers");
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_course = jsonObject.getJSONObject("courses");
                                    SubjectName = (String) studentDetails_course.get("CourseName");
                                    TeacherName = studentDetails_obj.getString("NAME");
                                    StartTime = jsonObject.getString("StartTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    EndTime = jsonObject.getString("EndTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    student_list_class_schedule_sunday.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(SubjectName, TeacherName, StartTime, EndTime));
                                } else if (day.equals("2")) {
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teachers");
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_course = jsonObject.getJSONObject("courses");
                                    SubjectName = (String) studentDetails_course.get("CourseName");
                                    TeacherName = studentDetails_obj.getString("NAME");
                                    StartTime = jsonObject.getString("StartTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    EndTime = jsonObject.getString("EndTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    student_list_class_schedule_monday.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(SubjectName, TeacherName, StartTime, EndTime));

                                } else if (day.equals("3")) {
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teachers");
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_course = jsonObject.getJSONObject("courses");
                                    SubjectName = (String) studentDetails_course.get("CourseName");
                                    TeacherName = studentDetails_obj.getString("NAME");
                                    StartTime = jsonObject.getString("StartTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    EndTime = jsonObject.getString("EndTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    student_list_class_schedule_tuesday.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(SubjectName, TeacherName, StartTime, EndTime));

                                } else if (day.equals("4")) {
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teachers");
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_course = jsonObject.getJSONObject("courses");
                                    SubjectName = (String) studentDetails_course.get("CourseName");
                                    TeacherName = studentDetails_obj.getString("NAME");
                                    StartTime = jsonObject.getString("StartTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    EndTime = jsonObject.getString("EndTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    student_list_class_schedule_wednesday.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(SubjectName, TeacherName, StartTime, EndTime));

                                } else if (day.equals("5")) {
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teachers");
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_course = jsonObject.getJSONObject("courses");
                                    SubjectName = (String) studentDetails_course.get("CourseName");
                                    TeacherName = studentDetails_obj.getString("NAME");
                                    StartTime = jsonObject.getString("StartTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    EndTime = jsonObject.getString("EndTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    student_list_class_schedule_thursday.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(SubjectName, TeacherName, StartTime, EndTime));

                                } else if (day.equals("6")) {
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teachers");
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_course = jsonObject.getJSONObject("courses");
                                    SubjectName = (String) studentDetails_course.get("CourseName");
                                    TeacherName = studentDetails_obj.getString("NAME");
                                    StartTime = jsonObject.getString("StartTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    EndTime = jsonObject.getString("EndTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    student_list_class_schedule_friday.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(SubjectName, TeacherName, StartTime, EndTime));

                                } else {

                                    JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teachers");
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_course = jsonObject.getJSONObject("courses");
                                    SubjectName = (String) studentDetails_course.get("CourseName");
                                    TeacherName = studentDetails_obj.getString("NAME");
                                    StartTime = jsonObject.getString("StartTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    EndTime = jsonObject.getString("EndTime").substring(11, 19);
                                    student_list_class_schedule_friday.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(SubjectName, TeacherName, StartTime, EndTime));


                                }

                            }


                            ClassScheduleStudentAdapter classScheduleStudentAdatptersunday = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_class_schedule_sunday);
                            ClassScheduleStudentAdapter classScheduleStudentAdatptermonday = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_class_schedule_monday);
                            ClassScheduleStudentAdapter classScheduleStudentAdatptertuesday = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_class_schedule_tuesday);
                            ClassScheduleStudentAdapter classScheduleStudentAdatpterwednesday = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_class_schedule_wednesday);
                            ClassScheduleStudentAdapter classScheduleStudentAdatpterthursday = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_class_schedule_thursday);
                            ClassScheduleStudentAdapter classScheduleStudentAdatpterfriday = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_class_schedule_friday);
                            ClassScheduleStudentAdapter classScheduleStudentAdatptersaturday = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_class_schedule_saturday);
                            listViewStudentClass_Sunday.setAdapter(classScheduleStudentAdatptersunday);
                            listViewStudentClass_Monday.setAdapter(classScheduleStudentAdatptermonday);
                            listViewStudentClass_Tuesday.setAdapter(classScheduleStudentAdatptertuesday);
                            listViewStudentClass_Wednesday.setAdapter(classScheduleStudentAdatpterwednesday);
                            listViewStudentClass_Thursday.setAdapter(classScheduleStudentAdatpterthursday);
                            listViewStudentClass_Friday.setAdapter(classScheduleStudentAdatpterfriday);
                            listViewStudentClass_Saturday.setAdapter(classScheduleStudentAdatptersaturday);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }
/*
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("id", master_id);
                map.put("accessID", accessID);
                map.put("currentUser", master_id);
                return map;

            } */
        };


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try it with `switch()`. **You can differentiate the day by "DayOfTheWeek"** (I think).

**EDIT:** YOU CAN USE ArrayList to combine the day together.
Declare this globally;

```
List<JSONObject> dayone=new ArrayList<>();
List<JSONObject> daytwo=new ArrayList<>();
List<JSONObject> daythree=new ArrayList<>();
....
```

And in code

```
    JSONArray jarr=new JSONArray(responseString);
    for(int i=0;i<jarr.length;i++){
     JSONObject obj=jarr.getJSONObject(i);
    String day=obj.getString("DayOfTheWeek");
    switch(day){
     case "1":  //for sunday
     String classId=obj.getString(ClassRoom_ID);
     dayone.add(obj);   //object ob day one
    //...... parse data//
     break;
     case "2":  //for monday
//...... do your code//
    daytwo.add(obj);   //object ob day two
     break;
    case "3":
//...... do your code//
     break;
    case "4":
//...... do your code//
     break;
    case "5":
     break;
    case "6":
     break;
    case "7":
     break;
 }
}
for(JSONObject jobj: dayone){
    String classId=jobj.getString(ClassRoom_ID); //class id of dayone
}
```

**Note: after Java version 7 and up switch statements supports Strings**

Comment: i will try @Kiran

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph, Switch case not support string.

Comment: @HareshChhelana take a look at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/new-java-7-feature-string)

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph,Okay but it's required Java 7 version

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph, You have mentioned or highlight this things on your answer.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Okey. thanks for your suggestion ..:)

Comment: @KIranBennyJoseph i have made listView to populate the data.I got one problem that ,I have multiple of day=1 on my list.How can the multiple of 1 be combined on only 1 list

Comment: where to use ??
for(JSONObject jobj: dayone){
String classId=jobj.getString(ClassRoom_ID); //class id of dayone
}

Comment: @Ghimire see my answer

Comment: @HareshChhelana Java 7 has been around for 6 years... Why are you stuck thinking "Switch case not support string"?

Comment: @Ghimire now what?

Comment: Two ore more Sunday are Displaying as the JSON Data

Comment: @Ghimire I don't get you

Comment: I want to group the information as DayOfTheWeek=1.All the information of 1
must be displayed under "sunday"(i.e list item)

Comment: if you want that use adapter class and create the required view and use model class to display that. That is more big answer you need to google it

Comment: I have already done that .but not able to achieve the view in the layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138706/discussion-between-kiran-benny-joseph-and-ghimire).

Answer (score 1):

How about a `TreeMap<String, List<JSONObject>>`?

It'll group each list on the same day value under a single key.

```
Map<String, List<JSONObject>> map = new TreeMap<>();

JSONArray jarr=new JSONArray(responseString);
for(int i = 0; i < jarr.length; i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
    String day = obj.getString("DayOfTheWeek");

    // Get the list
    List<JSONObject> jsonList;
    if (map.containsKey(day)) {
       jsonList = map.get(day);
    } else {
        jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    }

    // Add to the list
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); // for example
    // obj.put(key, value);            // for example 

    jsonList.add(obj);

    // Update the list
    map.put(key, jsonList);

}
Log.d("grouped values", map.toString());
```

At the end, you'll have something that you could visualize like this

```
Map(
    1 -> [ ... ]
    2 -> [ ... ]
    3 -> [ ... ]
)
```

Comment: please check edit.can i get output like above from the above JSON Data.I am totally confused.nothing going right

Comment: I'm just showing how you can organize your Java data. I'm not answering how your XML layout is structured, if that is your question

Comment: thats not my question. just working on it, so i ask.

Comment: You could use a `HashMap`, but I like `TreeMap` here because you'll have ordered keys from 1 to 7 for the days of the week. The value of the map is just a list like you were doing in your question. With my answer,  there's no reason to have a new list for each `dayone`, `daytwo`, etc.

Comment: what is to be added on jsonList.add(...);

Comment: Well, in my answer a `new JSONObject`, but it can be whatever that you want to add to the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138710/discussion-between-ghimire-and-cricket-007).

Comment: you said that It'll group each list on the same day value under a single key.but it is not grouping.

Comment: Should be. How did you test that it wasn't? Your code in the chat never used `map` after putting the json list. And I only said you could visualize the data like the end, there, not that it would literally be that

Answer (score 0):

I believe above problem can be solved using following steps:

1. Create a pojo class for holding data. If you have json you can just convert from here. [json to pojo converter](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
2. Create parser to parser your data.
3. Create ArrayList to hold the list of pojo data objects which you get from parsing json.
4. Finally use this function to sort the data using.

---

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});
```

---